# Jquery: Clone and append items

Tags: jquery

How do you write a loop to append the rest of the items?

```
<div id="first">
<li><span>john</span></li>
<li><span>jane</span></li>
</div>

<div id="last">
<li><span>smith</span></li>
<li><span>doe</span></li>
</div>

$("#last span:first).clone().appendTo("#first li");
```

Comment: Rest of *which* items? Append where? Have you read up on [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each) and using the index of the element:

```
var $target = $('#first li');
$('#last span').each(function(i) {
    $(this).clone().appendTo($target.eq(i));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean all of the items in the last list, you don't need to loop.  just remove the :first filter from your selector like so:

```
$("#last span").clone().appendTo("#first li");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
newelement = element.cloneNode(bool)
```

see this exapmle ..may be it will help you